# Uri: I need //content://media/ but get file://mnt/sdcard/

Tags: java, android, upload, youtube

My goal is to upload a specific videofile to youtube from my app.

Here some code from my Method:

```
        File videoToPlayFile = new File(mSharedPreferences.getString("output_file", ""));


            Intent intent = new Intent();  


    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(videoToPlayFile), "video/*");
    Intent intent2 = YouTubeIntents.createUploadIntent(this,intent.getData());
    startActivity(intent2);
```

I get the error that the Uri path from intent.getData needs to begin with content://media, but when I take Logs it allways showas a path like file://mnt/sdcard/blablabla.mp4

Comment: Please add the language you are using and the system to the tags...